# Handling the result of a getter method call in generic code

Tags: c++

When I write generic code, and often also when I write non-generic code, I handle the result of a getter method call like this:

```
const auto& result = obj.get();
```

This has some advantages, such as if `get()` will later on be changed and will return some not-trivially-copyable object, or when in generic code you cannot say ahead the nature of what `get()` will return, `result` will not force any copy. The only limitation is that since `result` is a bind to the temporary returned by `get()` when `get()` returns by value, it has to be `const`, which can be fine in many cases anyway.

On the other hand, I saw many people having concerns about `const auto&` when `get()` returns some primitive type, for example `int` or `size_t`, compared to just writing `const auto result = obj.get();`, because there is the idea that some sneaky, hidden and unnecessary pointers are being generated under the hood when using references.

While it is true that with no optimization the `const auto& result = obj.get();` generates slightly more binary code, I see no evidence of it being true when the optimizations are switched on.

So is there really any problem with writing `const auto& result = obj.get();` for all the use cases? Are there some not-optimizable cases in which it will perform worst?

Comment: Problem with `const auto&` is that it's usually difficult to get lifetimes right. What's wrong with relying on return value optimization?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen if you write `const auto result` and `f()` is returning by reference, you'll force a copy of the value. What is wrong with the lifetime in the `const auto&` version?

Comment: I've seen things like `A& f() {A a; return a;}` far too often, so I'm very suspicious about any function that returns reference. I guess if you manage lifetimes correctly in your project then it's not really wrong.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you are right, my example might be confusing, but by `f()` I meant also member functions, which often can return also by reference.